# How to get a safecontrol entry into manifest.xml with WSPBuilder project

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder, safecontrols

Upon taking the default sharepoint master page for MySite, making some changes, and making a wsp out of it with WSPBuilder, I come to these errors in my logs:

http://spoint/MySite/_catalogs/masterpage/MySite.master - An unexpected error has been encountered in this Web Part. Error: The control with virtual path '_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx' is not in the safe controls list for web at URL 'http://spoint/MySite'., Source: [UnsafeControlException: The control with virtual path '_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx' is not in the safe controls list for web at URL 'http://spoint/MySite' (stack trace omitted)

http://spoint/MySite/_catalogs/masterpage/MySite.master - An unexpected error has been encountered in this Web Part. Error: The control with virtual path '_controltemplates/DesignModeConsole.ascx' is not in the safe controls list for web at URL 'http://spoint/MySite'., Source: [UnsafeControlException: The control with virtual path '_controltemplates/DesignModeConsole.ascx' is not in the safe controls list for web at URL 'http://spoint/MySite'  (stack trace ommited)

So, this masterpage does in fact use these OOTB controls and so I guess I need to get them safecontrolled.  And I guess I want to do this via the manifest.xml.  But I do not see how to make WSPBuilder do this.

Answer (score 2):

WSPBuilder will only create SafeControls tags for objects that inherits from the "Control" class. This is to speed up processing of the WSP package. 
A quick fix, could be to create a empty class that inherits from webcontrol and use the same namespace as the ASCX.